# R using limits to find data in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, limits

I have a large data frame filled with numbers and a second data frame with limits (a high and low acceptable range) for each column. Im wondering how I can use the high and low limits to find data that falls outside of that range for each column. I can do this with a for loop, but it is a messy solution (and I'm sure inefficient) so I'm wondering if there is another way.

For example

```
#Create a data frame with values ranging from 0-10
sampleData <- data.frame(replicate(9,sample(0:10,10, rep=TRUE)))

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
1  1  7  9  0  7  3  0  0  8
2  4  8  3  4  9  6  3  2  3
3  9  7  5  2  7  5 10  9  4
4  2  6  2  1  3  9  4  3  9
5 10  2  2  6  4  7  4  9  7

#Have another data frame with our limits
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
1  1  7  3  4  7  3  0  0  3
2  4  8  9 10  9  6  3  2  8
```

I would want to know which rows have failed based on the values being outside our limits for that column. So failures would be

```
Col 1: 3,5
Col 2: 4,5
Col 3: 4,5
Col 4: 1,3,4
Col 5: 4,5
Col 6: 4,5
Col 7: 3,4,5
Col 8: 3,4,5
Col 9: 4
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use base R `mapply`. Assuming your limits dataframe is called `limits`. We pass the columns parallely from both the dataframes and select the indices which extend the limits.

```
mapply(function(x, y) which(x < y[1] | x > y[2]) , sampleData, limits)


#$X1
#[1] 3 5

#$X2
#[1] 4 5

#$X3
#[1] 4 5

#$X4
#[1] 1 3 4

#$X5
#[1] 4 5

#$X6
#[1] 4 5

#$X7
#[1] 3 4 5

#$X8
#[1] 3 4 5

#$X9
#[1] 4
```

Comment: 47 seconds, damn :) I'll delete mine as it is exactly the same.

Comment: @LeoP. oops..Happens :)

Comment: Yay! Goodbye for loop! Thank you for your response and help works perfectly after I realized limits was a matrix and not a data frame :(.